# c fgets segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I've written a function which should return a string of input text, with the new line character replaced with the end of string character. For some reason a segmentation fault occurs during the fgets process (it never reaches test2). No one I've asked about this can explain it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

p.s. I'm calling this function like this:

```
char search[256];
getSearch(search);
```

// getSearch function

```
char* getSearch(char searchText[256]) {
    printf("test1\n");

    printf("Search text: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(searchText, 256, stdin);
    printf("test2");
    int i;
    for (i=0; searchText[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (searchText[i] == '\n') {
            searchText[i] = '\0';
            i--;
        }
    }   
    char *search = searchText;
    return (search);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimum compilable program in your question that demonstrates this behavior, so others can compile, run and verify the problem. Also change `printf("test2");` to `printf("test2\n");` and you'll probably find that your segmentation fault is not within `fgets()` at all.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Also, tell us what input you're providing to the program.

Comment: Insure the return value of `fgets(searchText, 256, stdin)` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Is `getSearch(()` properly prototyped/declared before being called?

Comment: Instead of the loop, you can use `size_t length = strlen(searchText); if (len > 0 && searchText[len-1] == '\n') searchText[len-1] = '\0';`.